# MyPy signature of method incompatible with supertype

Tags: python, mypy

This is a recurring question, but I could not find the solution for my specific problem in the many questions there are in StackOverflow.
I have a Superclass with the following method:

```
def load_from_path(self, filepath: IO[Any], mode: str = "r", **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
    with open(filepath, mode, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        return self.load_from_fileobj(f, **kwargs)
```

This method is then inherited by a subclass which calls it as follows:

```
def load_from_path(self, filepath: IO[Any], **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
    return super(PickleHandler, self).load_from_path(filepath, mode="rb", **kwargs)
```

To reproduce the problem run mypy in the following code:

```
from typing import IO, Any

class BaseFileHandler:
    def load_from_fileobj(self, file: IO[Any], **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        return "hi"
    def load_from_path(self, filepath: IO[Any], mode: str = "r", **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
            return self.load_from_fileobj(filepath, **kwargs)

class PickleHandler(BaseFileHandler):
    def load_from_path(self, filepath: IO[Any], **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        return super(PickleHandler, self).load_from_path(filepath, mode="rb", **kwargs)

handler = PickleHandler()
obj = handler.load_from_path("fakefile.txt")
print(obj)
```

When running MyPy, I get `Signature of "load_from_path" incompatible with supertype`. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It'd probably help if you provided a [mre]

Comment: These are clearly incompatible signatures. Your design is broken, and mypy is pointing that out to you. You will need to change your class design. Maybe don't give these classes an inheritance relationship.

Comment: I have to inherit it because the `load_from_fileobj` is an abstract method that differs between Handlers. In the mock example for reproducibility it only returns a string but in actuality it uses the different methods depending on the file extension to load properly (either yaml or json, etc.).

Comment: That doesn't sound like a reason to inherit at all. If `load_from_fileobj` is abstract, that means it's functionality your base class is *not* providing to your subclasses. Your subclasses have to implement it themselves, which they could do with or without inheriting.

Comment: Something like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=eb4179878ade3554c619964384baca5e) (with other errors fixed too)?